# Photoresistor Switch

Tags: arduino-uno, relay, digital, resistor, photoresistor

How would I use a photoresistor like a switch. My issue is it is always bleeding out a little bit of power and always on. Is there a way to connect it to a digital pin and when a resistance of xxx is ment, set another digital pin to On?

Comment: First off, what is the circuit you are using with the photoresistor. What is the type, you get ones which have a light blocking casing allowing only IR through, or is it clear, if its clear it will pick up any light that leads to another point you can add, where is the sensor placed. There are other things to use other than an arduino, like a comparator. Have a look at this http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/13318/2944 it has a few points there for you to start with

Comment: Without a schematic, how can we help you?

Answer (score 1):

To turn an analog signal into a digital signal, at some sort of threshold xxx, you need to either condition it in electronic circuitry, with something like an amplifier or a comparator, or read the analog signal directly and apply the threshold in software.

You likely need to connect the photoresistor as half of a voltage divider, as in [Why do you need a second resistor when using a photoresistor/LDR?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/7921/6628)